# How do I set the layout of setListAdapter when I'm not using an ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview that I want to change the font size of.

Of course, doing this works with some hardcoded data:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<SimpleCursorAdapter>(this, R.layout.list_view));
```

But I would like it to take my cursor, so I have

```
mContactList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But in that case, I can't change my layout to be my list_view. Is there any way to go about this oro do I have to take my cursor data and put it into an array first.

This is where I have my adapter:

```
private void populateContactList() {
    Cursor cursor = getContacts();
    fields = new String[] { ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME };
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.entry, cursor, fields,
            new int[] { R.id.contactEntryText });
    mContactList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

EDIT: Got it. Turns out, I just needed to edit the contactEntryText TextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
    this,
    android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
    mCursor,
    new String[] {"String1", "String2"},
    new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I looked into what you gave me, and it was that I needed to edit text1 and text2. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for custom listviews you need to extend baseadapter [link here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html)
and make your own adapter where you can specify the layout xml to be used for each or all elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html).